# Return ID from partitioned table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, insert, sequence

When I insert a record I need to return the inserted id by `RETURNING`. The problem is that the table is partitioned and in partitioned table I can't use `RETURNING`. I run multiple queries at once so I'm in dire need of `RETURNING`. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a parent's table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent AS (
  id not null default nextval('parent_id_seq'::regclass)
  ... other columns ...
);
```

Whether you're using a rule or a trigger to divert the INSERTs into the child tables, immediately after the INSERT you may use:

`SELECT currval('parent_id_seq'::regclass);`

to get the last `id` inserted by your session, independently of concurrent INSERTs, each session having its own copy of the last sequence value it has obtained.

Answer (score 4):

Without having an overview of how you are currently managing your partitioned tables, it is relatively difficult to assess what you can do to circumvent this limitation.  Assuming you are using a trigger paradigm, in order to get `RETURNING` working as expected, you will have to change the `RETURN` clauses in your `BEFORE INSERT` functions from `NULL` to `NEW`, as the `RETURNING` clause will never receive the inserted values from the former case ( since they are never actually inserted into the master table ).  Making this change will pass the inserted rows through to the master table as well, allowing the `RETURNING` clause to receive results.

However, this means a double write occurs, so an `AFTER INSERT` trigger function will be required to remove the duplicated elements.  While this obviously incurs additional overhead and effectively halves efficiency, it will still have less impact than `RULE` paradigms ( which might take just as much working around anyway ), except of course in bulk insert scenarios.  It's a performance trade-off for consistency and maintainability, but as long as that's understood and the benefits of using partitioned tables in the first place are keeping SLA's met, I think it's an acceptable concession.

Here is the full [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/721bd/2) to show what I have described in action.  Note that the `NewID()` function at the top is just to show how this would work without having an available sequence and is in no way a suggestion that the function itself is a good idea in any way ( there are plugins for proper global UIDs if you want to go that route ).